# Onsen-ui: SlidingMenu doesn't update

Tags: onsen-ui

is there a way to update a sliding menu in Onsen? I want to show a different menu after a login. I already have the 2 version of the sliding menu (and they work, if I login, exit from the app and reopen the app)....
But I'm not able to find a way to tell the menu "after the login change the view".

I already put a refresh method inside the controller, that is called after the login (and I saw that the call works, but the view remain the same)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used this? http://onsen.io/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html#method-setMenuPage

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes, but my problem is the content of the menu (maybe I explained in the wrong way). I have 2 list of menu voices: one public (news, events, timetable) and one private (that add some voice, like "profile","exames", etc). I'm not able to tell to onsen to change the content of the menu view after the login

Answer (score 1):

After successful login execute function that will execute this onsen predefined function

```
menu.setMenuPage('newMenu.html', {closeMenu: true});
```

where `newMenu.html` is the id of your second menu template.